# Generating XML from SQL existing XSD file (complex)

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xsd

I have an XSD file. I get data from SQL and fill data to dataset. 
note: I get 1000 records from SQL.

I want to make this; generate XML file exisiting xsd format.

Here is my XSD.:

```
 <xs:element name = 'automation'>
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name = 'auto' type = 'AutoType' minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = 'unbounded' />
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

```
<xs:complexType name = "AutoType">
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name = "autoKodu" type = "xs:string" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' /> <!-- v -->
     <xs:element name = "autoAdres" type = "xs:string" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' /> <!-- v -->
     <xs:element name = 'bill' type = 'BillType' minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = 'unbounded' />
  </xs:sequence>
```

```
 <xs:complexType name = "BillType">
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name = "dateOne" type = "xs:date" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' /> 
     <xs:element name = "dateTwo" type = "xs:time" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' /> 
     <xs:element name = 'point' type = 'PointType' minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = 'unbounded' />

  </xs:sequence>
```

```
<xs:complexType name = "PointType">
  <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name = "plate"  minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' > <!-- v -->
     <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9])*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
     <xs:element name = "aa" type = "xs:string" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' /> 
     <xs:element name = "bb" type = "xs:decimal" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' /> 
     <xs:element name = "cc" type = "xs:string" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' /> 
     <xs:element name = "dd" type = "xs:decimal" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' />
     <xs:element name = "ee" type = "xs:decimal" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' /> 
     <xs:element name = "ff" type = "xs:decimal" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' />
     <xs:element name = "gg" type = "xs:decimal" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' />
     <xs:element name = "hh" type = "xs:decimal" minOccurs = '1' maxOccurs = '1' />
  </xs:sequence>
```

I have created xsd class using xsd.exe 
I added it to solution.

```
var data = new myClassOrSmthng? { ??? I do not know how to get datas from dataset here. }

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myClassOrSmthng));
                using (var stream = new StreamWriter(myPath)) serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Visual Studio Command Prompt, run the following command to create the class file:

```
xsd.exe /c automation.xsd (the XSD file you have)
```

Add that class file to your project (e.g. `Automation.cs`).

Then, you can serialize the XML using that class:

```
StringReader objStringReader = new StringReader(strXML);
XmlSerializer objXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Automation));
Automation automationInstance = (objXmlSerializer.Deserialize(StringReader) as Automation);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I already did Automation.cs. what should i write strXML for ?

Comment: The example assumes your content is in a string called strXML.

Comment: I am also searching same solution let me know if you have something. I will update if I build.